# Add loading gif while page loads/queries VB.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vb.net

I am trying  to display a loading symbol while the page loads, as on a button click it takes roughly 40 seconds to load the data, and I want a placeholder.

I have tried to use jquery as shown:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(window).load(function () {
                $(".loader").fadeout("slow");
            })
</script>
```

The .loader class CSS looks like this:

```
.loader

{
position: fixed;   
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url('images/loading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

I receive an error when I run the project:
"Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'fadeout'"

What could be the issue?

Comment: It's `fadeOut()` not `fadeout()` (notice the capital O)

Comment: Why tag vb.net if it's Javascript?

Comment: Normally, you'd use `fadeIn` to slowly show the loading gif and then only hide it when the data has loaded.  Do you have a trigger/event you can hook into when the data has loaded?   Is the data loading on page load or via an ajax request (you mentioned on a button click).

Comment: Sorry there is a <div class="loader"></div> in the body

Comment: @freedomn-m The data loads on button click, so I would like the loading icon to show after button click and end when data is loaded. I have tried several sources on this and I can't get any to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just a small mistake I figured out is that.

`fadeout` should be `fadeOut`

So,

```
   $(window).load(function () {
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
   })
```

would work for sure. :)